# Creating disk image

Tags: linux, partitioning, script

I cannot understand how to create an image file with desired layout.

`4Mb of free space | 32 Mb partition`

First, I need to create the partition table. The following part works:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=<image.img> bs=1M count=32
parted -s <image.img> mklabel msdos mkpart primary ext2 8192s 32M
```

Now I need a file system. The following part doesn't give me what I want:

`mkfs -t ext2 -E offset=8192 <image.img> 36M`

This command doesn't break the layout (4Mb of free space + 32Mb partition), but the partition itself is broken (gparted cannot recognize it as ext2)

I was told that mkfs can see the partition I created with parted, so i don't need to specify the offset. However, going without the offset makes matters worse: mkfs rewrites the entire image and 4Mb of free space are gone:

`mkfs -t ext2 <image.img>`

The only way that works is creating the layout on the physical disk.

`sudo parted -s /dev/disk mklabel msdos mkpart primary ext2 8192s 32M`

Note that now I have /dev/disk and /dev/disk**1** that represents the partition.
Creating the filesystem on that partition works perfectly.

`sudo mkfs -t ext2 /dev/disk1`

But I don't need to create partition on the physical disk, i need an image file. And I cannot dump the physical disk into an image because I'm writing a script for dynamic image creation.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the image size should be 36MiB instead of 32MiB:

```
$ truncate -s 36M test.img
```

(You can stick with your `dd` approach if you don't want sparse.)

`parted` doesn't seem to have a way for us to specify partition size instead of partition end:

```
$ parted -s test.img mklabel msdos mkpart primary ext2 8192s $((36*1024*1024/512-1))s
```

(For the record, `M` in parted doesn't refer to MiB but MB.)

Now the layout should be correct:

```
$ fdisk -l test.img
Disk test.img: 36 MiB, 37748736 bytes, 73728 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xc9c7e736

Device     Boot Start   End Sectors Size Id Type
test.img1        8192 73727   65536  32M 83 Linux
```

Apparently `offset` should be in byte:

```
$ mkfs.ext2 -E offset=$((8192*512)) test.img 32M
mke2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Discarding device blocks: done
Creating filesystem with 32768 1k blocks and 8192 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 4e527d5c-ad0f-4073-861b-c3e14bba676a
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
        8193, 24577

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

$
```

P.S. There's also the nice `-P` switch in `losetup` btw.

Comment: `$(())` might not work in all kinds of shell. Replace it with whatever works in the shell you use, or simply the answers after manual calculation.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! It looks like the image was created successfully. I was able to mount it and copy some files to it, and when I re-mount it, the files are still there. But when I write this image onto SD card, gparted recognizes that FS is ext2, but complains that FS contains errors: **Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdf1. Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.** I tried 2 SD cards with no success.

Comment: What's the sector size (logical) of `/dev/sdf` (make sure it is still the card reader upon your run) when you `fdisk -l` on it? Also how exactly did you mount it before the write and how exactly did you write to the card?

Comment: For the record, I just tried writing an image created with the exact commands in my answer to an SD card, and I can mount the filesystem on the card afterwards. I didn't have any further manipulation to the image before the write though.

Comment: Logical sector size is 512 bytes. For writing I used `sudo dd if=test.img of=/dev/sdf status-progress`. For mounting the image file I used `sudo losetup /dev/loop0 test.img && sudo kpartx -a /dev/loop0 && sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt`

Comment: No idea then. Although I suggest you try `losetup -P` (assuming you util-linux isn't too old) instead of `kpartx`, and make sure you unmount the filesystem and detach the image before writing. Also try mkfs on the loop device partition instead of running it on the image file directly (which save you the offset and size setting as well).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I ended up using a combination of our proprietary code and what I've learned about fdisk. Still have no idea what was wrong, but now everything is fine. Gparted still complains about the FS being a **little** messed up, but it's working.